# How to get info_buyRequest in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi i need to view one additional product attribute in magento admin panel. i need to get info_buyRequest->projectid. My database table is **sales_flat_order_item** my field Name is **product_options**

My record is given below

```
a:7:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:9:{s:2:"id";s:3:"715";s:7:"product";s:3:"288";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:2:{i:143;s:2:"69";i:144;s:2:"71";}s:7:"options";a:4:{i:79;s:3:"165";i:80;s:3:"166";i:78;s:3:"163";i:81;s:3:"359";}s:15:"attachment_hash";a:1:{i:215;s:32:"cbe019a075d376c0632dae49774370bb";}s:9:"projectid";s:2:"39";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:11:"reset_count";b:1;}s:7:"options";a:4:{i:0;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Coating";s:5:"value";s:21:"UV - Ultra High Gloss";s:11:"print_value";s:21:"UV - Ultra High Gloss";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"79";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"165";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:1;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Colors";s:5:"value";s:18:"Full Color 2 Sides";s:11:"print_value";s:18:"Full Color 2 Sides";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"80";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"166";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:2;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Paper";s:5:"value";s:20:"14pt Thick Cardstock";s:11:"print_value";s:20:"14pt Thick Cardstock";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"78";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"163";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:3;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:13:"Need a Design";s:5:"value";s:20:"Yes, I need a Design";s:11:"print_value";s:20:"Yes, I need a Design";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"81";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"359";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}}s:15:"attributes_info";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Quantity";s:5:"value";s:4:"1000";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Turnaround";s:5:"value";s:15:"4 Business Days";}}s:11:"simple_name";s:34:"2.75x4 Flyers-1000-4 Business Days";s:10:"simple_sku";s:33:"275x4-flyers-1000-4 Business Days";s:20:"product_calculations";i:1;s:13:"shipment_type";i:0;}
```

I need to get projectid in magento admin panel

> admin/sales_order/view/order_id/43/ page

How can i get it please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look `getAdditionalData()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`

Try

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $itemId => $item){
    $item->getAdditionalData('projectid')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento version 2, just load the order by the `order_id` from the order repository. After doing so, you will get the `info_buyrequest` inside the data, which you can get by `getBuyRequest()`, and deserialize it by using `json_decode` or calling the Magento tools. The data you are showing from `buy_request` is from Magento version 1, which uses the PHP deserializer to do it, and it is not supported in Magento version 2.